How to delete all "background" file buffers?
In Vim and Neovim how do I close all buffers that I currently do not have open? That is, across all tabs and windows I will have some file buffers open. There is similarly a set that are not open, and I want to delete them.
I am unsure if How to delete all empty buffers in Vim? helps me because I am not considering only buffers that are 'empty', but any buffer that isn't displayed to me. Maybe I don't know what empty means in this context.
Vim: Close All Buffers But This One does not answer my question because it would only close buffers except for the one where the cursor exists.
In rough pseudocode this is what I think I want:
for buffer in loaded_buffers {
    if buffer.not_open_anywhere() {
        buffer.delete()
    }
}

The desire to have this type of functionality is to follow a simple workflow for changing what I am working on:

Open file buffers for what I want to work on next.
Purge the unclean (ahem, I mean, delete the buffers that are not opened).


Here is Efficient way of cleaning up the buffer list. But first make sure you fully understand What is the difference between loaded and unloaded buffers.

Also note that most of old buffers are kept by Vim as your "editing history" (only names without text data). Most of the time, I believe, people seek to delete them due to excessive amount of info displayed by plugins/gui/widgets/whatever. But the real fix is to setup your UI view, not to purge "history data" instead.

Yes, it all boils down to why you want to close all those buffers. Performance? Cramped UI? Just because?

You might also find this plugin useful: https://github.com/axkirillov/hbac.nvim
